# getStaticProps() in Nextjs is not displaying the page source

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am following a udemy course about ReactJS which includes a section about Nextjs. I am following the instructor step by step and I don't seem to be getting the same result as he gets.

This is a simple application which displays a list of details of some meetings. Currently, I am trying to use `getStaticProps()` so that the HTML page source is displayed as well.

My problem is that I can't see the page source even with using `getStaticProps()`.

This is the page I am working on:

```
import MeetupList from "../components/meetups/MeetupList";
const DUMMY_MEETUPS = [
  {
    id: "m1",
    title: "first meetup",
    image:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533167649158-6d508895b680?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1189&q=80",
    address: "Some Address 5, 12345",
    description: "This is the forst meetup",
  },
  {
    id: "m2",
    title: "second meetup",
    image:
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533167649158-6d508895b680?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1189&q=80",
    address: "Some Address 6, 12345",
    description: "This is the second meetup",
  },
];

const HomePage = (props) => {
  return <MeetupList meetups={props.meetups} />;
};
```

This is the `getStaticProps` function:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {

  // fetch data from API (not fetching anything currently)
  return {
    props: {
      meetups: DUMMY_MEETUPS,
    },
    // revalidate: 1, // will be regenrated after this number of seconds
  };
}

export default HomePage;
```

This is `_app.js`:

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import Layout from "../components/layout/Layout";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

This is a screenshot for the page I am generating:
[image]

However, this is the page source (As you can see, no text from the displayed one is showing here!):

[image]

Comment: It is normal not seeing content in the root div since its spa. But you should see the meetups if you look at the page you used that meetups array.(where you map through it.) 

Have you wait the props.meetups arrau in MeetUps component parameters? Then, since it is an array you passed down. You should map throug it and display the content you want to display. I'm just asking for clarification because i can't see the usage of the props.meetups array in meetups component.

Comment: I've also followed the same course, but in my case it worked perfectly fine. try using the files provided by the instructor on github.